# VBA and Internet Explorer: fill in an input box

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I'm new to making interactions between VBA and Internet Explorer, but I've read many things online and couldn't figure out the problem in my code. I just want to retrieve the 'Username' box on a website and add a value inside. So I retrieved all input boxes into a collection of HTML elements, but then that collection is empty:

```
Dim Collect As IHTMLElementCollection

With IE
    .navigate "http:xxxxxxxxxx"
    .Visible = True
End With

Do While IE.Busy
Loop

Set Collect = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
MsgBox Collect.Length
End Sub
```

This will give a message box with "0". If I toggle a breakpoint before the end of the code and I "watch" the variable `Collect`, I can see there are 17 items inside, one of them being the username 'inputbox', with name 'tfUserName'. Can you help me please?

---

**EDIT:** I found that the problem comes from this code:

```
    Do While IE.Busy
    Loop
```

Which I replaced with this:

```
    Do Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop
```

And now everything works fine. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: can you post the HTML for the input box?

Answer (score 0):

Validate the collection against null instead to determine if it contains elements

```
If Not Collect Is Nothing Then
  For Each htmlElement In Collect
    If Not htmlElement.getAttribute("username") Is Nothing Then
       htmlElement.setAttribute("value", "licou6")
       Exit For
    End If
  Next
End If
```